# Retrieve data from mem cache

Tags: process, memory, exit

My application writes to a log file and for some reason it stopped writing to that file suddenly. We have restarted the application to fix this glitch. Is it possible to retrieve the missing log somehow from some memory dump/cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Even if there were the possibility of dumping the memory of the application to read the content of the unwritten logs, once you restarted the application the old process ended, and its memory is gone.